# Why does this not go into the else-if block?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
function checkValues(data, key) {
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    if (d == key) {
        console.log(i + "\n");
        return i;
    }
  });
  return -1;
}

var arr = [2, 3, 7, 1];
var x = 1;

if (x == 2) {
    console.log("if!");
}
else if (checkValues(arr, x) != -1) {
    console.log("else if!");
}
else {
    console.log("else!");
}
```

It's going into the else block. I certainly hope it's not something obvious.

https://jsfiddle.net/0ppfj19c/

Comment: Because of the final index of your array. it's `1`, so your else if triggers.

Comment: Because checkValues() always returns -1.

Comment: Work on creating minimal test cases. Why "is such and such if/else [not] run" is answerable by looking at the result of the condition: what is it, and why? Work backwards from there, presumably by examining the function evaluation by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return` in your `.forEach()` callback only returns back to the `.forEach` mechanism; it does not cause a return from `checkValues()`.

I think you want `.findIndex()`:

```
function checkValues(data, key) {
  return data.findIndex(function(d) {
    return (d == key);
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, `.findIndex()` is not supported in Internet Explorer (at least as far as the last MDN update), but [there is a polyfill available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) at the MDN page.

Answer (score 1):

The return you are using in the callback for the forEach loop does not actually break out of the entire call to checkValues because it is inside of `forEach`'s execution context. As a result, *your code is always returning -1*.

A better way would be to store the value.

```
function checkValues(data, key) {
    var index = -1;
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        if (d == key) {
            index = i;
        }
    });
    return index ;
}
```

However, a refactor would probably go even farther. `indexOf` does work on arrays for primitive values like this. You could simply do this:

```
function checkValues(data,key){
    return data.indexOf(key);
}
```

A simple check would be `[2, 3, 7, 1].indexOf(1)` which yields `3`.